# jQuery lazyload plugin with horizontal scroll for smartphone site

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am using jquery_lazyload plugin.
When I use it with horizontal scroll div, it seem to stop working on simulating mobile devices of Chrome / Firefox DevTools and real smartphone(Android, iOS).
Once I scroll to the position where I can't see the horizontal scroll div, the plugin starts working again.
I would appreciate it if you would give me some advice.

images is like this

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" data-original="http://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" alt="" class="lazyload">
```

js code is like this

```
$('.lazyload').lazyload({
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    effectspeed: 500
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heng3rv0/65/show